# Error fetching OAuth credentials: "Missing required parameter [code_verifier]."

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm encountering an issue with my OAuth implementation, specifically when trying to fetch credentials. The error message I'm receiving is:

Error fetching OAuth credentials: "Missing required parameter [code_verifier]."

I'm using Symfony with the knpu/oauth2-client bundle to integrate with an OAuth 2.0 provider (e.g., Twitter). The specific provider class I'm using is \Smolblog\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Twitter.

Here are relevant portions of my Symfony configuration (knpu_oauth2_client.yaml), especially related to the Twitter provider:

knpu_oauth.yaml :

````
```type: generic
provider_class: '\Smolblog\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Twitter'
client_id: '%env(resolve:TWITTER_CLIENT_ID)%'
client_secret: '%env(resolve:TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET)%'
redirect_route: connect_twitter_check
redirect_params: {}
# Other relevant configurations```
````

```
public function redirectToTwitter(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
{
    return $clientRegistry
        ->getClient('twitter')
        ->redirect(['users.read'], ['code_challenge']); // Scopes you need
}

#[Route(path: '/Connexion/twitter/check', name: 'connect_twitter_check')]
public function connectTwitter(Request $request, ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
{}
```

authenticate method :

```
 {
     $client = $this->clientRegistry->getClient('twitter');
     //dd($client);
     $accessToken = $this->fetchAccessToken($client);
     // dd($client);
     return new SelfValidatingPassport(
         new UserBadge($accessToken->getToken(), function () use ($accessToken, $client) {
             /** @var TwitterUser $twitterUser */
             $twitterUser = $client->fetchUserFromToken($accessToken);
             dd($twitterUser);
             $email = $twitterUser->getEmail();
             // dd($email);
             // dd($accessToken);
             // 1) have they logged in with Twitter before? Easy!
             $existingUser = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['twitterId' => $twitterUser->getId()]);
             // dd($existingUser);
             if ($existingUser) {
                 return $existingUser;
             } else {
                 // 2) do we have a matching user by email?
                 $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);
                 // dd($user);
                 if (!$user) {
                     /** @var Particulier $user */
                     $user = new Particulier();
                     $user->setEmail($email);
                     $user->setPassword($this->encoder->hashPassword($user, '@user0123456'));
                     $user->setTypeCompte("Particulier");
                     $user->setTel("+221765897845");
                     $user->setPrenom("nom");
                     $user->setNom("nom");
                     $user->setcivility("Mr");
                 }
```

I have this error after clicking the authorization button:

Questions:

1. How can I ensure that the required parameter [code_verifier] is properly included in the OAuth request?
2. Are there specific configurations in the Twitter Developer App that I should check to address this issue?
3. Is there a known issue or workaround related to the "Missing required parameter [code_verifier]" error in the knpu/oauth2-client bundle?

Comment: In the auth url , the cod_challenge and the code_challenge_method are not blank. The code_challenge_method is S256 . In the authenticate method, I have tried to get the code_verifier, but I'm wondering why I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out after updating :

```
#[Route(path: '/Connexion/twitter', name: 'app_twitter_start')]
    public function redirectToTwitter(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $codeVerifier = bin2hex(random_bytes(64));

        // URL-encode the code verifier
        $urlEncodedCodeVerifier = urlencode($codeVerifier);

        // Use SHA-256 to hash the URL-encoded code verifier
        $codeChallenge = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(hash('sha256', $urlEncodedCodeVerifier, true)), '+/', '-_'), '=');

        // Log or print the values for debugging
        echo "Code Verifier: $codeVerifier\n";
        echo "Code Challenge: $codeChallenge\n";

        // Store the code verifier in the session
        $session->set('oauth2verifier', $codeVerifier);


        $authUrl = $clientRegistry
            ->getClient("twitter")
            ->redirect(["users.read","offline.access","tweet.read"], ["code_challenge" => $codeChallenge,"code_challenge_method" => "S256"]);
        // dd($authUrl);
        return $authUrl;
    }
```

and this in the authenticate method :

```
$client = $this->clientRegistry->getClient('twitter');

        $session = $request->getSession();
         // Get the code verifier from the session
         $codeVerifier = $session->get('oauth2verifier');
         // echo "Code Verifier for Access Token Request: $codeVerifier\n";
         $authorizationCode = $request->query->get('code');
        // rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(hash('sha256', $codeVerifier, true)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
         // dd($authorizationCode);
        // dd($codeVerifier);

         $provider = $client->getOAuth2Provider();
         $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                    'code' => $authorizationCode,
                    'code_verifier' => $codeVerifier,
                 ]);
 return new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge($accessToken->getToken(), function () use ($accessToken, $client) {

                /** @var TwitterUser $twitterUser */
                $twitterUser = $client->fetchUserFromToken($accessToken);
 .........}
```

I forgot include the default scopes offline.access and tweet.read